# Combine associated data from single data sets

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have taken over a project which already contains tons of data.
The given format is not the best and contains only single data sets. Most of them belongs to the same "event". I want to combine those data sets.

The given data-sets are in this format:

**Given Data Set:**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [title] => Party 1
        [start] => 2017-06-14
        [end] => 2017-06-14
        [className] => Array
            (
                [0] => yyy
                [1] => zzz
            )

        [color] => #26B99A
        [zeit] => xxx
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [title] => Party 2
        [start] => 2017-04-27
        [end] => 2017-04-27
        [className] => Array
            (
                [0] => xxx
                [1] => yyy
            )

        [color] => #26B99A
        [zeit] => zzz
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [title] => Party 2
        [start] => 2017-04-28
        [end] => 2017-04-28
        [className] => Array
            (
                [0] => xxx
                [1] => yyy
            )

        [color] => #26B99A
        [zeit] => zzz
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [title] => Party 2
        [start] => 2017-04-29
        [end] => 2017-04-29
        [className] => Array
            (
                [0] => xxx
                [1] => yyy
            )

        [color] => #26B99A
        [zeit] => zzz
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [title] => Party 3
        [start] => 2017-07-30
        [end] => 2017-07-30
        [className] => Array
            (
                [0] => xxx
                [1] => yyy
            )

        [color] => #26B99A
        [zeit] => zzz
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
        [title] => Party 3
        [start] => 2017-07-31
        [end] => 2017-07-31
        [className] => Array
            (
                [0] => xxx
                [1] => yyy
            )

        [color] => #26B99A
        [zeit] => zzz
    )......
```

In this case, there would be a single "Party 1", and combined "Party 2" and "Party 3"

The result therefore should look like this:

**Expected Result**

```
[0] => Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [title] => Party 1
    [start] => 2017-06-14
    [end] => 2017-06-14
    [className] => Array
        (
            [0] => yyy
            [1] => zzz
        )

    [color] => #26B99A
    [zeit] => xxx
)

[1] => Array
(
    [id] => 6
    [title] => Party 2
    [start] => 2017-04-27
    [end] => 2017-04-29    <---- end date edited
    [className] => Array
        (
            [0] => xxx
            [1] => yyy
        )

    [color] => #26B99A
    [zeit] => zzz
)


[2] => Array
(
    [id] => 11
    [title] => Party 3
    [start] => 2017-07-30
    [end] => 2017-07-31     <---- same
    [className] => Array
        (
            [0] => xxx
            [1] => yyy
        )

    [color] => #26B99A
    [zeit] => zzz
)
```

Therefore, I used a PHP function which formats it by the event's title:

**PHP:**

```
function formateEvents($event_array){
$events = array();

foreach($event_array as $event)
{
    if(!isset($events[$event['title']]))
    {
        $events[$event['title']]['id']           = $event['id'];
        $events[$event['title']]['title']        = $event['title'];
        $events[$event['title']]['start']        = $event['start'];
        $events[$event['title']]['end']          = $event['end'];
        $events[$event['title']]['name']         = $event['title'];
        $events[$event['title']]['className']    = $event['className'];
        $events[$event['title']]['color']        = $event['color'];
        $events[$event['title']]['zeit']         = $event['zeit'];
    }else{


        if(strtotime($event['start']) < strtotime($events[$event['title']]['start']))
        {
            $events[$event['title']]['start']    = $event['start'];
        }

        if(strtotime($event['end']) > strtotime($events[$event['title']]['end']))
        {
            $events[$event['title']]['end']    = $event['end'];
        }
    }
}

return array_values($events);
}
```

This works fine for data sets like theese above.
**But:** the problem is, that I have event data from the years ago as well, which often have the same title. The event duration in this case is then over multiple years. I want to prevent this in a way that only data with the same name, as well as connected days should be combined.

The only way, that comes in my mind to do that, is to check if the days are contiguous ... like 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02, 2018-01-03 should be the same event... if there is a day missing in between, it should count as another event

Comment: I think would need to specify for how long could an event be connected to another with the same title. But having that set, you can accumulate the results in another array indexed by the title and evaluate each of them comparing to the dates you have. Do you understand me?

Comment: I got the idea, but it is impossible to generalize event durations... they can be from 1 day up to 3 months. Some of them are from December to January - so I neither can seperate them by year.

Comment: I understand that. But you said: "I want to prevent this in a way that only data with the same name, as well as connected days should be combined". How can you decide if the days are connected in this scenario?

Comment: The only way, that comes in my mind is to check if the days are contiguous ... like 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02, 2018-01-03 should be the same event... if there is a day missing in between, it should count as another event

Comment: Ok, that's helpful. Please add this information to the question itself so everyone can read it. :)

Comment: I added an answer but I think the solution considering the contiguous days would probably be better using a recursive function... if no one answers I will think about it this afternoon. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is much more complex than what I wanted, but it's working.
So, let me explain it.

**First** I map all the events by their title.

```
$eventsIndexedByTitleAndEndDate = array();
foreach ($event_array as $event) {
    $eventTitle = $event['title'];
    $eventEnd = $event['end'];

    $eventsIndexedByTitleAndEndDate[$eventTitle][$eventEnd] = $event;
}
```

**Then** I run through this data to find the dates I want to use, and then I map this dates into another array still using the title of the event as main index.

```
$eventDates = array();
foreach ($eventsIndexedByTitleAndEndDate as $eventTitle => $eventIndexedByTitle) {
    $datesFromIndexedTitle = (array_keys($eventIndexedByTitle));

    $start = $datesFromIndexedTitle[0];
    $end = $datesFromIndexedTitle[0];
    foreach ($datesFromIndexedTitle as $dateFromIndexedTitle) {
        $nextDayFromEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($end)));
        if ($dateFromIndexedTitle == $nextDayFromEnd) {
            $end = $dateFromIndexedTitle;
        } elseif ($dateFromIndexedTitle > $nextDayFromEnd) {
            $eventDates[$eventTitle][] = [
                'start' => $start,
                'end' => $end,
            ];
            $start = $dateFromIndexedTitle;
            $end = $dateFromIndexedTitle;
        }
    }
    $eventDates[$eventTitle][] = [
        'start' => $start,
        'end' => $end,
    ];
}
```

**After** I have all the dates mapped, I run through this array using reference to update the keys with the data from the array indexed by Title, updating the start/end date as they should.

```
foreach ($eventDates as $title => &$eventDate) {
    foreach ($eventDate as &$eachEvent) {
        $start = $eachEvent['start'];
        $end = $eachEvent['end'];

        $eachEvent = $eventsIndexedByTitleAndEndDate[$title][$start];
        $eachEvent['start'] = $start;
        $eachEvent['end'] = $end;
    }
}
```

I believe there is probably an easier way to do it, but I cannot think about one solution now, though this was quite a good exercise to do. :)

Comment: That's almost the same function as mine. - The problem if an older event has the same title as a newer one still remains. :-)

Comment: Check it now. :)

Comment: Well... if I save each `$eachEvent` into a new array and return it at the end of the fkt, it works as I wanted, thank you for that! :)

Comment: Just be careful, in this particular case, if you do have a lot of events this will affect the performance **severely**, so I would recommend finding a way to update the database for this at some point. Since this function (once the database would be correct) wouldn't be necessary anymore.

Comment: I alrady added a new field `event_id` to the table and use this function to combine the events accordingly ;-) , afterwards I just can get the events I want by it's new event id